# Python: floating point input getting returned as integer ouput?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I hope you're all having a fulfilling day. I'm learning python and I wrote this little Ohm's Law calculator as a learning exercise. The program is working fine except that even though I have cast user input as "float" the functions only return integer answers. (ex. if I choose voltage and enter 0.7 amps it returns an incorrect integer) Here's my code:

```
# ohm's law calculator

# These functions perform the calculations, but the result currently only prints as an integer.
def voltage(i, r):
    return i * r



def current(r, v):
    return r / v


def resistance(i, v):
    return i / v




# First user interface menu    

print "What value would you like to solve for?"

print "1. Voltage"
print "2. Current"
print "3. Resistance"

choice = raw_input(">>> ")



#These are calling the functions.

#This gives values to "i" and "r" from user input as floating point numbers the print line calls the "voltage" function and prints out the results of its calculation using "%d"
if choice == "1":
    i=float(raw_input("Enter current:"))
    r=float(raw_input("Enter resistance:"))
    print "%d volts" % voltage(i, r)


elif choice == "2":
    r=float(raw_input("Enter resistance:"))
    v=float(raw_input("Enter voltage:"))
    print "%d amps" % current(r, v)



elif choice == "3":  
    i=float(raw_input("Enter current:"))
    v=float(raw_input("Enter voltage:"))
    print "%d ohms" % resistance(i, v)

#This line is here partly because its funny, and partly because I thought it would be cool to create my own error message   
else:
print "Invalid number. Your system will crash momentarily."
```

I would also appreciate any tips on making this code a little cleaner. i. e. more readable or working more efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: If you want general feedback, once it's tested and working head to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `%d` to output a float, use `%f`.

Better yet use the new `format` function instead, and let Python choose the best representation:

```
print "{0} volts".format(voltage(i, r))
```

Comment: (or just use a bare print, `print voltage(i, r), 'volts'`)

Comment: Decided to try the "format" function just for kicks, and I like it even more.